# Iframe no funciona, error X-Frame-Optins utilizando Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Estoy tratando de mostrar una página web en una etiqueta `iframe`, sin embargo esta me muestra el siguiente error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.segurossura.com.co/paginas/default.aspx' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Así aparece en mi navegador ***Chromium***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación anexo la función que estoy ejecutando:

```
function showOptions(divId) {
    switch (divId) {
        case "visitWebPage": {
            Swal.fire({
                width: 1820,
                title: "<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>",
                html: '<iframe width="1720" height="850" src="https://www.segurossura.com.co/paginas/default.aspx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
                showCloseButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                focusConfirm: false,
                confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
                confirmButtonAriaLabel: "Thumbs up, great!",
                cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
                cancelButtonAriaLabel: "Thumbs down"
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}


<div class="col-md-4" onclick="showOptions('visitWebPage')">
    <span class="message-medium shadow display-2 d-block mb-4">Presiona para ampliar la información</span>  
</div>
```

**Nota:** Cabe recalcar que si cambio la url de la página web que deseo mostrar, esta funciona correctamente, el problema pasa específicamente con algunas páginas.

¿Alguna idea, solución o aporte?

Comment: ¿Alguna idea, solución o aporte?